# How can a function from an infinite set to a subset be one-to-one?

Tags: functions

Consider a function on R defined by f(x) = $\frac{x}{1+\left|x\right|}$

We can prove through substitution that f(x1)= f(x2) ⇒ x1 = x2 and hence, the function is injective.

However, I am confused as to how this can be so.

The domain of the above function is R, the set of real numbers (which is an infinite set).
The range of the function is the interval (-1, 1), which is also an infinite set.

However, the range is a subset of the domain, so shouldn't the domain have more elements than the range? Doesn't this mean the function can't be injective?
How can each element of the domain be mapped onto a distinct element of the codomain, but the range has fewer elements than the domain?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of infinities. I suggest you look up Hilbert's Hotel, and try to wrap your head around that one. It's a common starting point for getting an intuition on infinity.

Comment: This is because the cardinalities of the sets agree. The interval $(-1,1)$ has the same amount of elements with $\mathbb{R}$. In set theory, injective function $f: X \to Y$ shows that $X$ has an equal or lesser cardinality than $Y$.

Comment: A simpler example: there is a 1-1 (in fact, a bijection) between $\mathbb{N}$ and the set of even numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Pondering $f(n) = n+1$ on the set of natural numbers might help?

Comment: Consider the inverse function $g(y)=\frac{y}{1-|y|}$ as $(-1,1) \to \mathbb R$, so $g(f(x))=x$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ and $f(g(y))=y$ for $y \in (-1,1)$.  This too is both an injection and a surjection so there must be at least as many points in $(-1,1)$ as in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is infinity. In fact, one definition of an infinite set is one where you *can* create an injection from the set to a proper subset of itself.

Here are some simpler examples:

- The function $f(n) = 2n$ is an injection from the integers to the even numbers.
- The function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ is an injection from the interval $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 0.5]$.

This leads to the idea of [set cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) (which is the "number" of elements in a set) in which you get things like countable versus uncountable infinities - sets where you can "count" every element like the natural numbers and rational numbers are all the same size, which is smaller than the size of the interval $[0, 1]$ or the real numbers as a whole. There's a separate concept called "measure" which *does* give you a way to say that $[0, 1]$ is a smaller set than $[-10, 10]$ or $(0, \infty)$, but that's distinct from the cardinality.

Comment: A really simple example is the map from $\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$ to $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$ given by $f(n)=n+1$.